# onclick event not applying border around checkbox

Tags: css

in my Spring web Flow, while click on Confirm button it should highlight the checkbox if it 
is uncheck and form should not be submitted. if it is checked form should be submitted

```
<form:form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-box" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" value="
    <c:out value="${status.value}"/>">
    <input type="hidden" name="_<c:out value="${status.value}"/>">
    <span onclick="submitForm('confirm')">Confirm</span>
    <span onclick="submitForm('cancel')">Cancel</span>
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(event){
        if(document.getElementId('check-box').checked){
            doc.form[0]._eventId_value=event;
            doc.form[0].submit();
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementId('check-box').style="border-style:solid,border-width:5px;"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Woah... What's going on here?

Comment: @Mahnax: please suggest me how to format my question to see properly

Comment: It would seem that someone did it for you.

Comment: thanks mu is too short, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use border:5px solid #ccc; or any color for that matter

Comment: thanks . styles are not getting applied around checkbox if i click on confirm without selecting checkBox

Comment: You should also check you are escaping your quotes properly "/>"> this might not work right